# Getting all points in vector (between two points)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opengl

Lets say I have 2 points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2). And I can draw vector from point (x1,y1) to point (x2,y2). How can I get all possible  points between them at for example every 10 pixels?

Simple visualization:
[image]

Comment: Getting all of them would require a lot of space (there are too many of them, a whole [continuum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_(set_theory))). You probably meant the points with integer coordinates approximating the line, right?

Comment: Yes. As I said `at every 10 pixels for example`

Comment: As @dasblinkenlight alread pointed out, there is an infinite number of points inbetween. If you're interested at getting the points as for drawing a line, please look at the "Bresenham Algorithm"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vector between point A and a point B is B-A (x2-x1, y2-y1)
If you normalize that vector, and multiply it by the factor you want (it seems you want a distance of 10px, so your factor is 10), you can get all the points by adding it to the a current point (which initially is the origin A) until you reach the end point B.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a smaller stepVector and add him step by step.

PseudoCode:

```
stepVector = yourVector / 10
Point1 = basePoint + stepVector
Point2 = Point1 + stepVector
...
```

or something line

```
stepVector = yourVector / 10
Point1 = basePoint + stepVector
Point2 = basePoint + (stepVector * 2)
Point3 = basePoint + (stepVector * 3)
...
```